# Angular ng-select value is not getting refreshed unless clicking the ng-select

Tags: angular11, angular-ngselect

I am trying to set the value of ng-select based on the other field value using form valuechanges.
The value is set but not showing up until i click on the ng-select box. the bindLabel is not getting refreshed.

```
<ng-select [items]="routes$ | async" bindLabel="combinedRoute" formControlName="route">
    <ng-template ng-typetosearch-tmp>
        <div class="ng-option disabled">
           Type route...
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ng-notfound-tmp let-searchTerm="searchTerm">
        <div class="ng-option disabled">
            No routes found for "{{searchTerm}}"
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    </ng-select>
```

component:

```
deptCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(data=> {
        let routeCtl = this.form.get('route');
        routeCtl .setValue(data);
  });
```

Can anyone help how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `updateValueAndValidity` method, it was like it has the value but change detection is not detecting that.

```
deptCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(data=> {
        let routeCtl = this.form.get('route');
        routeCtl .setValue(data);
        this.form.controls["route"].updateValueAndValidity(); // update value and validity.
  });
```

Another way to do it. Call `changeDetection` manually.

```
constructor(cd:ChangeDetectionRef){}

deptCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(data=> {
        let routeCtl = this.form.get('route');
        routeCtl .setValue(data);
        this.cd.detectChanges(); //Detect changes
  });
```

Comment: Thanks but it is still not updating.

Comment: can you update your question with data what you are getting in 'items' and when you are setting the value type of 'data' ?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue myself. I'm updating the value using tap on an observable. If I use a different component it updates fine, this only happens with ng-select.